# Searching for value in pointer: Reading 4 bytes given uint8_t pointer memory start location and size

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to search through a chunk of memory for a 4 byte hex value (0xAABBAABB) and then copy out the 4 bytes before that into a separate variable.

0xAABBAABB is the message terminator and I'm after the 4 bytes that precede this.

I'm given the start of the location of the data in memory from a *uint8_t and a message size. So the *uint8 holds the first 2 bytes of the message.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this? Do you have any code or pseudocode?

Comment: This sounds more like a *task* than a question. What have you tried, and what were the problems you ran in to ?

Comment: Please clarify. Your last sentence about the pointer holding the first two bites of the message

Comment: I can read the message 2 bytes at a time:
`void searchMessage(*uint8_t message, int size)
{
int value = 0;
for(int counter = 0; counter <=size;counter++)
{
if (*(message + counter)==0xEE)
{
// get preceeding 4 bytes
}
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
uint8_t *msg = ...;
int msgsize = ...;

...

uint8_t bytes[4];
bool found = false;

msg += 4;
msgsize -= 4;
while (msgsize >= 4)
{
    if (*(uint32_t*)msg == 0xAABBAABB)
    {
        memcpy(bytes, msg-4,  4);
        found = true;
        break;
    }

    ++msg;
    --msgsize;
}
```

Or this:

```
uint8_t *msg = ...;
int msgsize = ...;

...

const uint8_t term[4] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xAA, 0xBB};
uint8_t bytes[4];
bool found = false;

msg += 4;
msgsize -= 4;
while (msgsize >= 4)
{
    if (memcmp(msg, term, 4) == 0)
    {
        memcpy(bytes, msg-4,  4);
        found = true;
        break;
    }

    ++msg;
    --msgsize;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. Your first answer has worked a treat. It was the cast `*(uint32_t*)msg` and `memcpy(bytes, msg-4,  4);` that I was mainly missing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write whole code for you, but if you can read 2 bytes it will be quite simple to read 4 bytes. Just read 2 bytes, shift and read again 2 bytes. Assuming that `readUInt8();` is returning 2 bytes from your message.

```
std::uint16_t readUInt16()
{
    const std::uint16_t firstByte = readUInt8();
    const std::uint16_t secondByte = readUInt8();

    std::uint16_t value = 0;
    value |= firstByte << 8;
    value |= secondByte;

    return value;
}
```

and then check if `readUInt16() == 0xAABBAABBu` if yes take previous 4 bytes. Remember to check if message size aligns to 4 bytes.

Comment: Since this is a *mulitbyte* issue, Endianness comes into play.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews sure thing. Above code is in Big Endian.